# Count column value in column PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am looking for a solution for counting occurrences in a column. I want/have to keep my Dataframe ungrouped, therefore I cannot use `groupBy()` or `agg()` functions.

Can you think of a solution with a `withColumn()` function which does the following:

| col1 | count_col |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 9 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 20 | 4 |
| 20 | 4 |
| 30 | 9 |
| 20 | 4 |
| 20 | 4 |
| 30 | 9 |
| 30 | 9 |
| 30 | 9 |
| 30 | 9 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 30 | 9 |
| 30 | 9 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 30 | 9 |

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Whats stopping you to `groupBy` get the counts , and `join` it back to your base `DataFrame`

Comment: @Vaebhav I have 30-40 columns where I have to apply this

Comment: `counting occurrences in a column`?

Comment: What about the window function?

Comment: @koiralo ok, but how?

Comment: smth. like: df.withColumn("count_col", count().over(Window.partitionedBy("col1")))

Answer (score 2):

You can get an ungrouped DataFrame using a [`window`](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-window-functions/) function:

```
# Import 
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Group by object
grouped = Window().partitionBy('col1')

# Add a column per window defined above
df = df.withColumn('count_col', count('col1').over(grouped))
```

Gives you back:

```
+----+---------+
|col1|count_col|
+----+---------+
|  10|        3|
|  10|        3|
|  10|        3|
|  20|        4|
|  20|        4|
|  20|        4|
|  20|        4|
|  30|        9|
|  30|        9|
|  30|        9|
|  30|        9|
|  30|        9|
|  30|        9|
|  30|        9|
|  30|        9|
|  30|        9|
+----+---------+
```

This method is equivalent to `groupby.transform` in `pandas`